# Can't access Dolphin samba share in Win10

Tags: kubuntu, samba, dolphin

I use Kubuntu 17.10.I have a ntfs partition mounted at boot and with uid=1000 and gui=1000 like my user. In Dolphin I can share it with right click, properties, share, share with samba. Under `Everyone` I set `---` and under my name I set `Full Control`. I can't check `Allow Guests` checkbox (?!).

In Win10 if I try to mount this drive, I enter IP address and I get username and password prompt. However, I get `access denied` all the time. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add your user name to the samba password database? As in - without quotes: "sudo smbpasswd -a your-user-name"

Comment: Well, thank you, that was it! Although, this should be made obvious for user through GUI, when creating a share. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your user name to the samba password database? As in:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a your-user-name
```